# If user is equal to string

Tags: django

So I am trying to set a privilege to certain people on the system, showing them an extra button to delete a certain event. This is the start of the if statement:

```
{% if user == occurrence.created_by  %}
```

This works fine and I do need this but I also need an OR statement which compares the user to strings, for example `user == "admin"`.

I get nothing and I know the string is right because I printed out `{{ occurrence.created_by }}` and just used that string that produces, so what is the difference between using `{{occurrence.created_by}}` and `"admin"`

Any ideas?

Comment: Supply the actual code you're having trouble with, especially the OR statement that causes you to "get nothing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing `user` and `occurrence.created_by` works because they are both user instances. Comparing `user` and `"Admin"` will always be `False`, because one is a user and the other is a string.

You can compare `"admin"` to `user.username`.

```
{% if user == occurrence.created_by or user.username == "admin" %}
```

However, a better approach might be to use [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#permissions).

```
{% if user == occurrence.created_by or perms.my_app.delete_occurrence %}
```